# How can i prevent 'Simple_form_for' from redirecting or refreshing when I click on 'Create'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

My problem is whenever I'm typing to create a new object, the form refreshes by itself and unable to save it to the database

```
  # POST /customers
  # POST /customers.json
  def create
    respond_to do |format|
      @refund = Refund.all.map{ |c| [c.status, c.id]}
      @customer = current_user.customers.build(customer_params)
      @customer.refund_id = params[:refund_id]

      if @customer.save
        format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: "You have successfully added a refund for #{@customer.last_name}." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @customer }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
       <%= simple_form_for @customers, remote: true do |form| %>
       <%= select_tag(:refund_id, options_for_select(@refunds), :prompt => 
   "Select A Status") %>
     <%= form.input :first_name %>
     <%= form.input :last_name %>
    <%= form.input :phone_number, placeholder: 'Ex: 786-690-8990' %>
      <%= form.input :amount, placeholder: 'Ex: Customer\'s refund amount' %>
    <%= form.input :note,  placeholder: 'Ex: Your tax refund has been accepted and is processing...' %>
   <%= form.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-lg btn-danger' %>
  <% end %>
 </div>
 ##
```

---

##

Comment: can you explain more what does it mean refresh by itself ? if you click submit it should call CREATE action and of course it should refresh because it is a server side action, is it your issue that no errors shown on the page after saving failed ?

Comment: The problem is as i'm filling the form, all the information disappear before I even click the submit button.

Comment: Did you press **Enter** on any field when you were filling the data . ?

Comment: No, I did not. I'm not sure if it's a syntax or gem's error.

Comment: can you post the html formed in the DOM from the browser

Comment: Can you show the rails log for when you type into the form? Don't hit enter key. Just tabs to go to next fields. Also do not submit the form yet.

Comment: Are you sure this `simple_form_for @customers, remote: true do |form|` here is `@customers` and not `@customer`?

Comment: Hey Singh, I fixed the instance variable, but when i view the app on localhost or Heroku, it just keeps refreshing by itself.